# Schengen travel insurance for flight landing next day

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, spain, insurance, netherlands

So, I will be flying on 25th of December and reach Spain next day i.e. 26th of December. I have already applied for Schengen Visa but I have one doubt, will it get rejected because my insurance coverage is from 26th of December instead of 25th of December i.e. the cover starts when I will land in Spain not when I board.

Comment: Why did you get insurance that starts on the 26th? What will happen if you are taken seriously ill on the flight?

Comment: @DJClayworth the flight is at 10 PM in the night